# Connect via Wi-Fi using computer name instead of IP address

Tags: java, android, ip-address

I have been connecting two PCs via Wi-Fi and I'm using IP address to do this like the example below:

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.X.X";
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 8888);
```

My IP address regularly change so this is a hassle for me and I want to use the computer's name instead of this.  How is this possible?

EDIT:

From the replies below, I was able to do it this way on two PCs:

```
String ipAddress = "somename";
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress), 12345);
```

and this

```
String ipAddress = "somename";
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 8888);
```

but when I apply it on my Android app, it doesn't work.  Is there a special way to do it in Android?

Comment: You must have a name resolution system in place which Java can use for this. If Windows, maybe Android has WINS resolution? Try and use InetAddress' `.getByName("themachinenamehere")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an IP adress you can also use a hostname. For example if your server has hostname "foo.bar.com" you can use

```
Socket socket = new Socket("foo.bar.com", port);
```

In your local network you should be able to use the hostnames of the local pc's. I have just written a small example that sucessfully connects to my printserver:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class SocketTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws UnknownHostException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        //Create socket connection
           try{
             Socket socket = new Socket("printserver", 23);
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
             try{
                 while(in.read()!=-1){
                     String line = in.readLine();
                     System.out.println("Text received: " + line);
                 }
               } catch (IOException e){
                 System.out.println("Read failed");
                 System.exit(1);
               }

           } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             System.out.println("Unknown host: kq6py");
             System.exit(1);
           } catch  (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("No I/O");
             System.exit(1);
           }

    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work always. I can't remember exactly when and what the conditions were, but I definitely can remember it didn't work. I think it is OS dependent.

Comment: I have tried this and was able to do it successfully on my PC but it doesn't work on my Android device.  It force closes.